# How to preserve quotes in a bash parameter?

Tags: node.js, bash, shell

I have a bash script (Mac OS X) that in turns calls a Node.js command line application.

I normally call the Node.js app like this:

```
node mynodeapp events:"Open project"
```

Which node has no problem parsing as one parameter, in spite of the space between "Open" and "project".

I call my bash script like this:

```
. mybashscript.sh 2014-03-20 "Open project"
```

Inside the bash script I have:

```
EVENTSQUOTES=\"$2\"
echo node mixpanel-extract date:$1 events:$EVENTSQUOTES
node mixpanel-extract date:$1 events:$EVENTSQUOTES
```

Running the script produces:

```
node mixpanel-extract date:2014-03-20 events:"Open project"

Parameters: { date: '2014-03-20',
  events: [ '"Open' ] }
```

So although the `echo` output line looks fine, the `Parameters:` output from my Node.js app tells me that bash splits the parameter in two. I've also tried wrapping it in more quotes e.g. `EVENTSQUOTES='\"$2\"'` but it makes no difference.

Comment: @anubhava has an accurate answer to your question. Allow me to add one clarification: Only **syntactic** quotes have any impact on parsing. Any quote that you've escaped is data, not syntax (and any expansion result is *always* data, not syntax), so adding quotes inside your quotes is changing your data, not telling the parser to interpret what it sees differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use quote while calling also:

```
node mixpanel-extract date:"$1" events:"$EVENTSQUOTES"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
echo node mixpanel-extract "date:$1" "events:$2"
node mixpanel-extract "date:$1" "events:$2"
```

You need to quote the variable when you use it as well, otherwise word splitting will occur.

Comment: -1: You're not actually quoting every expansion here.

Comment: Eh, not going to argue. Copy'n'pasting from a question is always a bad idea, especially straight before going to bed. Now I feel like hiding in a dark corner since usually I'm the guy who complains about the lack of quotes. Thanks for the heads-up.